# Specify dynamic sort order with StructuredQueryBuilder

Tags: java, marklogic

When using MarkLogic 7 with the Java Client API, I am currently in the process of moving my query definitions from a `StringQueryDefinition` to a `StructuredQueryDefinition` allowing me to construct and manipulate the query programmatically.

With the string query I was able to use the sort operator with `sort:{my-sort-order}` successfully which in turn referred to names of predefined orders as specified in the query options (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_30002), but cannot find the API docs a related method allowing me to specify the sort order with the structured query builder.

What is the recommended way on how to specify the sort order when using a `StructuredQueryDefinition`?

**UPDATE** 
Based on Erik's proposal, this is how the code snippet currently looks like, but it doesn't solve the problem, since the `operator-state` has to go as child on the `query` element and not as child on the `search` element:

```
    RawStructuredQueryDefinition queryDef = qb.build(qb.and(qb.term(..), qb.rangeConstraint(...)));
    String sorting = "<operator-state><operator-name>sort</operator-name><state-name>" + orderBy + "</state-name></operator-state>";
    String combi = "<search xmlns='http://marklogic.com/appservices/search'>" + queryDef.toString() + sorting + "</search>";
    RawCombinedQueryDefinition combinedQueryDef = queryManager.newRawCombinedQueryDefinition(new StringHandle(combi), OPTIONS);
    // DOES NOT WORK, but will lead to MarkLogicIOException "Could not construct search results: parser error"
    // Possible solution is to modify the queryDef DOM your own
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with, basically I use the programmatic way on building a query with `StructuredQueryBuilder` and then inject the `operator-state`, referring to a pre-defined sort order in my options (`OPTIONS_ALL`):

```
org.jdom2.Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader(queryDef.serialize()));
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(orderBy)) {
    Element operatorState = new Element("operator-state", NAMESPACE_SEARCH);
    operatorState.addContent(new Element("operator-name", NAMESPACE_SEARCH).setText("sort"));
    operatorState.addContent(new Element("state-name", NAMESPACE_SEARCH).setText(orderBy));
    doc.getRootElement().addContent(operatorState);
}
RawStructuredQueryDefinition rawQueryDef =
                queryManager.newRawStructuredQueryDefinition(new JDOMHandle(doc), OPTIONS_ALL);
// ~~
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryManager.search(rawQueryDef, resultsHandle, start);
```

With

```
public static final Namespace NAMESPACE_SEARCH = Namespace.getNamespace("http://marklogic.com/appservices/search");
```

Answer (score 2):

We used the `<options>` tag of the `<search>` element sent to the server.
This requires an ugly string concatenation, but it does not require anything server-side other than an index on the sort property.

For the format of the XML, see this link or the search.xsd :
http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_33716

The idea is to generate an XML like this one :

```
<search xmlns='http://marklogic.com/appservices/search'>
  <query xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <collection-query>
      <uri>a_collection</uri>
    </collection-query>
  </query>
  <options>
    <sort-order type="xs:dateTime" direction="descending">
      <json-property>a_field</json-property>
    </sort-order>
  </options>
</search>
```

We did it like this :

1. First, build your StructuredQueryDefinition

   ```
   StructuredQueryDefinition queryDef = sb.collection("my_collection);
   ```
2. Build the `<options>` element seen above

   ```
   String xmlSortNode =
           "  <options>" +
           "    <sort-order type=\"xs:dateTime\" direction=\"descending\">" +
           "      <json-property>a_field</json-property>" +
           "    </sort-order>" +
           "  </options>";
   ```
3. Build the full `search` element

   ```
   String searchXml="<search xmlns='http://marklogic.com/appservices/search'>"
     + queryDef.serialize()
     + xmlSortNode
     + "</search>";
   ```
4. Execute the query

   ```
   queryManager.newRawCombinedQueryDefinition(new StringHandle(searchXml),"all");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

At present, StructuredQueryBuilder only builds criteria.  You would have to refer to persisted query options with the sort order or send a combined search with both the criteria and options.

Comment: Thanks, Erik, but unfortunately the `operator-state` seems to be part of the `query` element, which itself is produced by the `StructuredQueryBuilder` serialization, and therefore one has to manipulate the DOM -- which was something I wanted to avoid when using the programmatic API -- and can not just concatenate query and sort operator (which has to be dynamic in our case) like in the example: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_50826.

Comment: Would it work to use the search:sort-order element, which is part of the query options?  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_33716

Comment: I think @ehennum has a good point. Instead of changing the query for each different sort, change the search options instead. You have a `OPTIONS` in you code snippet, but you could try to build that dynamically based on search order needs..

Comment: With the problem that you have a lot of duplication in your option files. If you want to persist them on the server-side and have 10 search options with ascending and descending orders, you would end up in 20 files which would only differ in the sort spec. Sure with a template and some gradle magic all feasible...

Comment: The suggestion was for the client to send the complete query options with the query. In this approach, there would is no need to persist query options on the server and thus no duplication.

Comment: Ah ok, I misinterpreted then your original proposal, sorry. The problem that you have to interact directly with XML (see my UPDATE on the question) seems to remain though, which at least in my eyes is a kind of contradiction if you consider that programmatically constructing a query with the builder as a type-safe way avoiding to construct/manipulate the XML query directly.

Comment: In Java, you can use DOMs like JDOM2 or XOM to modify an options structure, which is a lot easier and more reliable than string manipulation. That said, we are tracking a feature request to enhance StructuredQueryBuilder to support sort: https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/61

Answer (score 1):

We’re tracking this [on GitHub](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/61). Please feel free to add information there.

Answer (score 0):

Sort order is considered an operator. Take a look at [operator-state](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_45570) and you'll find an example of sorting in a structured query.

Comment: Sure thing, I can use a raw XML string for constructing that kind of queries, but I was really asking for help on how to achieve this with the Java Client API and the `StructuredQueryBuilder`.